# Varnish 6.0lts won't handle secure websockets on a remote proxy?

Tags: ssl, caching, websocket, proxy, varnish

I'm having a hard time with this setup.  I have a node.js box serving HTTP on 3000, websockets on 3001, and secure websockets on 3002.  Out in front of that I have a remote Hitch/Varnish caching proxy on its own server that's listening on 443/80 and connecting the first server as its default backend via 3000.  A user who visits the site URL https://foo.tld hits the varnish proxy and sees the site, where some javascript on the site tells their browser to connect to wss://foo.tld:3002 for secure websockets.

My problem is getting websockets to pass transparently through to the backend.  In the VCL I have the standard

```
if (req.http.upgrade ~ "(?i)websocket") {
return (pipe);
}
```

and

```
sub vcl_pipe {
#Declare pipe handler for websockets
if (req.http.upgrade) {
set bereq.http.upgrade = req.http.upgrade;
set bereq.http.connection = req.http.connection;
}
}
```

Which doesn't work in this case.  To list what I have tried so far with no success:

1:  Creating a second backend in VCL named "websockets" that is the same backend IP but on either port 3001 or 3002 and adding "set req.backend_hint = websockets;" before the pipe summon in the first snippet above.

2:  Turning off HTTPS and trying to connect it over pure HTTP.

3:  Modifying varnish.service to try and make varnish listen on ports other than, or in addition to, -a :80 and -a :8443,proxy, in which cases Varnish simply refuses to start.  One attempt was to simply use HTTP only and attempt to run varnish on 3001 to get ws:// working without SSL but varnish refuses to start.

4:  Most recently I attempted the following in VCL to try and pick up client connections coming in on 3001:

```
if (std.port(server.ip) == 3001) {
set req.backend_hint = websockets;
}
```

My goal is for the Varnish box to pick up secure websocket traffic (wss://) on 3002 (via hitch at 443 using the normal secure websocket connection protocol) and have that passed transparently to the backend websocket server, whether SSL encrypted across that leg of the connection or not.  I have set up other, smaller servers like this before and getting websockets working is trivial if Varnish and the backend service are either on the same machine or behind a regulating CDN like Cloudflare, so it has been extra frustrating trying to figure out just what this remote proxy setup needs.  I feel like part of the solution is having Varnish or Hitch (not sure) listening on 3002 to accept the connections at which point the normal req.http.upgrade and pipe functions would come into play, but the software refuses to cooperate.

--------Update--

I have broken down the problem into the simplest form I can.  The main server (backend) is now serving plain HTTP on 8080 and WS:// on 6081.  I have removed hitch and TLS from the equation entirely, but even in this simplified form it is impossible to connect to websockets through Varnish.  I can verify that the Websocket server is working correctly on the backend.  Connecting to the backend IP address with a browser shows websockets functioning perfectly there.  It's Varnish that's the problem.

My current hitch.conf (not relevant here but provided per request):

```
frontend = "[*]:443"
frontend = "[*]:3001"

backend = "[127.0.0.1]:8443"    # 6086 is the default Varnish PROXY port.
workers = 4                     # number of CPU cores

daemon = on

# We strongly recommend you create a separate non-privileged hitch
# user and group
user = "redacted"
group = "redacted"

# Enable to let clients negotiate HTTP/2 with ALPN. (default off)
# alpn-protos = "h2, http/1.1"

# run Varnish as backend over PROXY; varnishd -a :80 -a localhost:6086,PROXY ..
write-proxy-v2 = on             # Write PROXY header


syslog = on
log-level = 1
# Add pem files to this directory
# pem-dir = "/etc/pki/tls/private"
pem-file = "/redacted/hitch-bundle.pem"
```

Current default.vcl (stripped down to almost nothing just for testing this.  The backend is NOT running on the same machine, it is remote):

```
# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.


backend default {
    .host = "remote.server.ip";
    .port = "8080";
}

backend websockets {
        .host = "remote.server.ip";
        .port = "6081";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.

    #Allow websockets to pass through the cache (summons pipe handler below)

if (req.http.Upgrade ~ "(?i)websocket") {
        set req.backend_hint = websockets;
        return (pipe);
    } else {
    set req.backend_hint = default;
    }



}

sub vcl_pipe {
    if (req.http.upgrade) {
        set bereq.http.upgrade = req.http.upgrade;
        set bereq.http.connection = req.http.connection;
    }
    return (pipe);
}
```

Varnish's systemd exec parameters:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
          -a http=:80 \
          -a proxy=localhost:8443,PROXY \
          -a ws=:6081 \
          -p feature=+http2 \
          -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
          -s malloc,256m \
          -p pipe_timeout=1800
```

Working in plain HTTP and insecure websockets like this, it should be very simple to get a working model.  I don't understand what could possibly be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Varnish Cache, the open source version of Varnish, doesn't support backend connections over TLS.

While you can offload TLS using Hitch, the connection to your websocket server will not be encrypted.

### Basic VCL example

Here's a very basic VCL example where web & websocket requests are split and sent to separate backends:

```
vcl 4.1;

backend web {
    .port = "3000";
}

backend ws {
    .port = "3001";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.Upgrade ~ "(?i)websocket") {
        set req.backend_hint = ws;
        return (pipe);
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = web;
    }
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    if (req.http.upgrade) {
        set bereq.http.upgrade = req.http.upgrade;
    }
    return (pipe);
}
```

### Need more input

However, I'm probably missing a lot of context. I also didn't specify a `.host` parameter in the backends, so the assumption is that all services are hosted locally.

Please add your full VCL, your Hitch config and the `varnishd` runtime parameters to your question. This will add context and allows me to come up with a better solution.

### What about Hitch?

If you terminate TLS in Hitch, both HTTPS & secure websockets will be handled by Hitch where the plain-text HTTP & websockets will still be directly handeled by Varnish.

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/terminate-tls-varnish-hitch for a Hitch tutorial that also explains how Varnish should be configured.

I'm a big advocate of using the `PROXY` protocol in Varnish. The hitch tutorial has a specific section about this: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/terminate-tls-varnish-hitch/#enable-the-proxy-protocol-in-varnish

### Custom ports

The standard ports to access the service are `80` for HTTP and insecure websockets and `443` for HTTPS and secure websockets.

If you want to use custom ports for the websockets, it is possible to configure them in Hitch and Varnish.

Let's say you want to main ports `3001` and `3002` for your websockets. This means you need 2 frontends in Hitch:

- One for HTTPs on `443`
- One for secure WS on `3002`

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/terminate-tls-varnish-hitch/#listening-address for more information about the frontend config.

Varnish on the other hand needs to have 3 listening addresses:

- One for HTTP on port `80` (`-a http=:80`)
- One for offloaded HTTPS & secure WS with `PROXY` support on port `8443` (`-a proxy=:8443,PROXY`)
- One for insecure WS on port `3001` (`-a ws=:3001`)

### Next steps

Please use the information and see if this helps to find a solution. If not, please share your VCL file, your Hitch config and `varnishd` runtime.

### Update

Now that you provided more input, the picture starts to become more clear. The fact that you eliminated the TLS part for now will make it a lot easier to debug.

Assuming the names of your listening interfaces for `varnishd` are `http` and `ws` (as mentioned in your systemd unit file), we can use the following `varnishlog` commands to debug:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqStart[3] eq 'http'"
```

This command will show logs for all log transactions where the `http` listening interface is used.

If you want to make it more granular, you can also add the request URL as a filtering criterium. This will narrow down the number of transactions:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqStart[3] eq 'http' and ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

> Please add a complete log transaction for one of the failed requests. This will help us understand why requests are failing.

You can do the same for requests on the `ws` listening interface by using the commands below:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqStart[3] eq 'ws'"
```

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqStart[3] eq 'ws' and ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

> I'm assuming you're successful at starting the `varnishd` program but unsuccessful at getting decent output out of Varnish. The `varnishlog` program will provide the insight we need. Please add the logging output to your question so I can look into it.

Comment: Even following your advice, I can't get the most basic HTTP/WS connection to work.  I completely emptied my default.vcl file to make sure nothing else I was doing could be interfering.  What I am describing is pure HTTP/WS now, with no use of hitch or HTTPS at all.  I'm just trying to get SOMETHING to work.  systemctl edit --full varnish now has it listening on 80 and ws=:6081 (works).  The backend server is running HTTP on 3000 and WS on 6081 (works via IP access) and default.vcl defines 2 backends for web and ws with the piping exactly as the example you gave above.  Nothing works.

Comment: @8protons Things are getting a bit more clear based on your input. I added some `varnishlog` commands for debugging. Please run them and add the output to your question. I'll examine that output and try to figure out what's going on.